# How do I fit a scroll into a portion of a circle without?

Tags: html, css, web, scroll, scrollbar

I have this right now:
https://ibb.co/iqaOXS

I would like to have this:
https://ibb.co/eDkCRn

And as you can see, the buttons are getting out of the circle. What do I do to make the buttons not trespass the circle border like that?

I would appreciate a solution in CSS and html only if possible, but anything is welcome!

Here's my code so far:

```css
    #one{
      border:2px solid black;
      border-radius:50%;
      height:90px;
      width:90px;
  
  
    }

    #unu{
      overflow:auto;
      position:absolute;
      top:20px;
      height:60px;
      width:80px;
      border:2px solid transparent;  
  
    }

    button {
      width:65px;
      height:40px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="one">
       <hr style="width:60px;">
       <hr style="position:absolute; left:15px; top:74px; width:70px; " >
       <div id="unu">
          <button>
              <p>
                  ONE
              </p>
          </button>
          <button>
              <p>
                 TWO
              </p>
          </button>
          <button>
              <p>
                  THIRD
              </p>
          </button>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `overflow:hidden` on #one?

Answer (score 1):

One clean way would be to wrap your content in a `div.content` element and apply `clip-path: circle`.

But currently Can I Use reports low compatibility (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path), so only use it if you know your audience.

```css
#one{
      border:2px solid black;
      border-radius:50%;
      height:90px;
      width:90px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: circle(45px at 50% 41%);
}

    #unu{
      overflow:auto;
      position:absolute;
      top:20px;
      height:60px;
      width:80px;
      border:2px solid transparent;  
  
    }

    button {
      width:65px;
      height:40px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div class="content">
       <hr style="width:60px;">
       <hr style="position:absolute; left:15px; top:74px; width:70px; " >
       <div id="unu">
          <button>
              <p>
                  ONE
              </p>
          </button>
          <button>
              <p>
                 TWO
              </p>
          </button>
          <button>
              <p>
                  THIRD
              </p>
          </button>
       </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```